# what is the best/secure way to implement the <a>?

Tags: html, href

Im new to web technology.
what is the best way implement  hyperlink event.
I don't want to reveal the page name on hyperlink when user inspect the web page in browser.I saw an example on amazon.in. they are just passing the link url in href.and the requesd page is showing. i want to achieve the same.
How can i do it? Please suggest..

Comment: I think you have to clearify what you actually want to achieve... What do you mean by "page name" ? The URL? The file path? An actual file (i.e. "test.html")? When inspecting Amazons `<a>` elements, they have a `href` attribute, but it's filled with probably ID's and so on... ... ...

Comment: this is what their <a> tag loks like
<a href="/mobiles-accessories/b/ref=nav_shopall_sa_menu_mobile_all_mobiles/280-1409862-8923743?ie=UTF8&amp;node=1389401031" >
</a>

Answer (score -1):

Websites like amazon use hyperlinks with the `<a>` element and a `href` attribute.

```
<a href="/gp/product/....">text or image</a>
```

You can add a `title` to show information when you hover the mouse over the link. Like chrisv said it's not clear what you mean by not revealing the page name.

Comment: ok lets say
<a href="/test/call/me?a=2&b=3">call me</a>
when user click on this link. i want to call callme.html.
How can i do this?

Comment: Using a url that is different from the filename is normally done by a webserver (like nginx or Apache) or by a web application. The terms to look for in this context are routing, rewriting, redirecting and proxy.

Comment: are you asking to have a page and then links to another page in the website? use <a href="page1.html">link to page 2</a>
    <a href="page3.html">link to page 3</a>
    <a href="page4.html">link to page 4</a>

Comment: ok i got your point. what is best approach to routing the url

Comment: Often when mapping URLs in the form of product/123 to an HTML page one uses a database combined with some template and a web framework. You could look at software like django(if you use Python) rails (with Ruby) or something similar if you know another programming language.